How to convert 1bit/pixel(depth) BMP image to 16bits/pixel BMP Image without using any predefined library in C language
So, basically my main goal is to implement zoom functionality on BMP levels which I did, but it only works on 16bits/pixel BMP images, Hence 1bit/pixel QR codes not working with that logic.
So If you can guide me on either conversation of 1bit/pixel QR BMP image to 16bits/pixel QR BMP image or directly zooming out 1bit/pixel QR BMP image without using any predefind library like opencv, sdl, gd graphics or any
Zooming out means, Multiply pixels size to zoom-level(passed by user). i.e. if BMP image is 300x300 and we zoom out by zoom-level 2, output BMP image is of 600*600, and image also gets zoomed and visible.
Any inputs/suggestions would be very helpful. Advance thanks.
Already tried to covert from 1bits/pixel to 16bits pixel by multiplying BMP width and height to zoom factor, pixels size does incerse as per requirement but QR is not getting zoomed. Below is API to make QR code based on qrcode data, This is clean original API(without my failed trials code written)
static int makeQr(char * file, const uint8_t qrcode[], double Zoom) {
    int size = qrcodegen_getSize(qrcode);
    int border = 4;
    uint32_t imageSize = (size+border*2) * 8;
    uint32_t rowSize =((imageSize + 31 ) / 32 ) * 4;
    // open output file
    int ret;
    FILE* fp = fopen(file, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
    return -1;
    }
    uint32_t bmp_header_sz = 14;
    //uint32_t bmp_dib_v3_header_sz = 40;
    uint32_t bmp_dib_v4_header_sz = 108;
    uint32_t bmp_color_pallet_sz = 8;
    bmpfile_t *result = (bmpfile_t*)malloc(sizeof(bmpfile_t));
    if (result == NULL) {
        
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    result->header.magic[0]=0x42; // B
    result->header.magic[1]=0x4D; // M 
    result->header.creator1=0x0;
    result->header.creator2=0x0;
    result->header.offset=bmp_header_sz + bmp_dib_v4_header_sz + bmp_color_pallet_sz;
    result->dib.header_sz=bmp_dib_v4_header_sz;
    result->dib.width=imageSize;
    result->dib.height=imageSize;
    result->dib.nplanes=1;
    result->dib.depth=1;
    result->dib.compress_type=0;
    result->dib.bmp_bytesz=rowSize * result->dib.height;
    //ESP_LOGI(__FUNCTION__, "result->dib.bmp_bytesz=%"PRIu32, result->dib.bmp_bytesz);

    result->dib.hres=0xec3;
    result->dib.vres=0xec3;
    result->dib.ncolors=2;
    result->dib.nimpcolors=2;
    result->dib.rmask=0xff0000;
    result->dib.gmask=0xff00;
    result->dib.bmask=0xff;
    result->dib.amask=0xff000000;
    result->dib.cstype=0x73524742;
    memset(result->dib.space, 0x00, sizeof(result->dib.space));
    result->dib.rgamma=0x40000000;
    result->dib.ggamma=0x00;
    result->dib.bgamma=0x00;
    result->header.filesz=bmp_header_sz+bmp_dib_v4_header_sz+result->dib.bmp_bytesz;
    //ESP_LOGI(__FUNCTION__, "result->header.filesz=%"PRIu32, result->header.filesz);
    

    // write bitmap file header
    ret = fwrite(&result->header, 1, sizeof(bmp_header_t), fp);
    //ESP_LOGI(__FUNCTION__, "fwrite ret=%d", ret);
    assert(ret == sizeof(bmp_header_t));

    // write bitmap information header(BITMAPV4HEADER)
    ret = fwrite(&result->dib, 1, sizeof(bmp_dib_v4_header_t), fp);
    //ESP_LOGI(__FUNCTION__, "fwrite ret=%d", ret);
    assert(ret == sizeof(bmp_dib_v4_header_t));

    // write color pallet 
    uint8_t pallet[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00};
    ret = fwrite(&pallet, 1, sizeof(pallet), fp);
    //ESP_LOGI(__FUNCTION__, "fwrite ret=%d", ret);
    assert(ret == sizeof(pallet));

    // write pixel data
    uint8_t *sdbuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(rowSize); // pixel buffer
    if (sdbuffer == NULL) {
        //ESP_LOGE(__FUNCTION__, "sdbuffer allocate error");
        free(result);
        fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }
    memset(sdbuffer, 0xff, rowSize);
    for (int row=0; row<result->dib.height; row++) { // For each scanline...
        int pos = result->header.offset + row * rowSize;
        //ESP_LOGD(__FUNCTION__, "pos=%d row=%d", pos, row);
        ret = fwrite(sdbuffer, 1, rowSize, fp);
        assert(ret == rowSize);
    }

    int row = 0;
    // write qr code pixel
    for (int y = -border; y < size + border; y++) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = -border; x < size + border; x++) {
            sdbuffer[index] = 0xff;
            if (qrcodegen_getModule(qrcode, x, y)) sdbuffer[index]=0x0;
            index++;
        }
        // write the same value to 8 rows
        for (int _row=0;_row<8;_row++) {
            int pos = result->header.offset + (result->dib.height - 1 - row) * rowSize;
            //ESP_LOGD(__FUNCTION__, "pos=%d row=%"PRIu32" y=%d size + border=%d", pos, result->dib.height - 1 - row, y, size + border);
            fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);
            ret = fwrite(sdbuffer, 1, rowSize, fp);
            assert(ret == rowSize);
            row++;
        }
    }
    free(sdbuffer);
    free(result);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}


Unrelated but don’t use magic numbers like 0x42 and 0x4D. You should use character constants instead which you list as comments right beside the assignment.
